# How can i optimize this erosion filter code?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, image-processing, optimization

I've implemented this Function that applies Erosion Filter to an image

```
void applyErosionFilter(QImage &input, int matrixSize)
{
    int filterOffset = (matrixSize - 1) / 2;
    int byteOffset = 0;

    uchar red, green, blue = 0;
    uchar morphResetValue = 255;

    uchar *data = input.bits();
    int stride = input.bytesPerLine();
    uchar *newdata = new uchar[stride * input.height()];

    int i = 0;
    for (int y = filterOffset; y < input.height() - filterOffset; y++)
    {
        for (int x = filterOffset; x < input.width() - filterOffset; x++)
        {
            byteOffset = y * stride + x * 4;

            red = morphResetValue;
            green = morphResetValue;
            blue = morphResetValue;

            for (int filterY = -filterOffset; filterY <= filterOffset; filterY++)
            {
                for (int filterX = -filterOffset; filterX <= filterOffset; filterX++)
                {
                    i = byteOffset + (filterX * 4) + (filterY * stride);

                    if (data[i] < red)
                        red = data[i];

                    if (data[i + 1] < green)
                        green = data[i + 1];

                    if (data[i + 2] < blue)
                        blue = data[i + 2];
                }
            }

            newdata[byteOffset] = red;
            newdata[byteOffset + 1] = green;
            newdata[byteOffset + 2] = blue;
            newdata[byteOffset + 3] = 255;
        }
    }

    input = input.fromImage(QImage(newdata, input.width(), input.height(), QImage::Format::Format_ARGB32));
    delete [] newdata;
}
```

it works pretty well, but I've been wondering if there is another way to do this in a more efficient way, perhaps there is a way to perform the computations on the GPU using openGL or so.

Comment: This can be optimized significantly, if `matrixSize` (let's call it N) is larger than 3. First of all, you can compose the square NxN structuring element as two line SEs of length N. Next, each line SE can be computed in O(1) per pixel, independent of N.

Comment: The easiest way I can think of, would be to calculate the `newdata` values for multiple lines in parallel (i.e. using multiple threads). You can definitely use OpenCL / OpenGL, but that would require a lot of boilerplate to get started.

Comment: How large is the matrix size ?

Comment: @CrisLuengo: would be fair to give the OP a reference.

Comment: @Yves: fair enough. [van Herk, Pattern Recognition Letters 13(7):517-521, 1992](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/016786559290069C).

Comment: @CrisLuengo sorry for this, but can you provide some illustrative code

Comment: I have [code for the van Herk algorithm](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/6411e8bf77e8a3b0b9b4743881dcbb9530836905/src/morphology/one_dimensional.cpp#L146), but it's not illustrative, as it has many complications to make it generic and as efficient as possible with normal C++ code. There already are many implementations, why don't you use one of the existing ones?

Comment: [Here is a CUDA implementation](https://github.com/VictorD/LTU-CUDA) described in [this paper](http://urn.kb.se/resolve?urn=urn:nbn:se:ltu:diva-8288).

Comment: @eike: using multiple threads in this case wouldn't be an option, because this function gets called from a for loop that already executes in parallel.
so I guess my only choice would be using OpenGL or OpenCL. although I'd prefer OpenGL as I'm already familiar with it. i guess that if i executed the innermost two loops on the GPU that would be great, but i'm not familiar with OpenGL compute shaders

Comment: @CrisLuengo: i've tried to use some of the existing Implementations but my problem was that i couldn't find any one compatible with Qt, all that i found needed some modifications in order to operate on QImages, & all of my project is already built on Qt, if you know of some implementation that makes use of QImages that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you every body.
I've found what i was looking for, and i wanted to share it with you.

```
QOpenGLTexture *m_texImageInput;
QOpenGLShaderProgram *m_shaderComputeH;

void initiateShader()
{
    if (m_texImageInput)
    {
        delete m_texImageInput;
        m_texImageInput = nullptr;
    }

    QImage img(":/image.png");
    m_texImageInput = new QOpenGLTexture(img.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGBA8888).mirrored());

    if (m_shaderComputeH)
    {
        delete m_shaderComputeH;
        m_shaderComputeH = nullptr;
    }

    m_shaderComputeH = new QOpenGLShaderProgram;
    m_shaderComputeH->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Compute, ":/csErosionFilter.fsh");
    m_shaderComputeH->link();
}

QSize getWorkGroups(int workGroupSize, const QSize &imageSize)
{
    int x = imageSize.width();
    x = (x % workGroupSize) ? (x / workGroupSize) + 1 : (x / workGroupSize);
    int y = imageSize.height();
    y = (y % workGroupSize) ? (y / workGroupSize) + 1 : (y / workGroupSize);

    return QSize(x, y);
}

void executeFilter(int radius)
{
    QOpenGLExtraFunctions *f = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->extraFunctions();

    // Process input image
    QSize workGroups = getWorkGroups(32, QSize(m_texImageInput->width(), m_texImageInput->height()));
    // Pass 2
    f->glBindImageTexture(0, m_texImageInput->textureId(), 0, 0, 0,  GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA8);
    f->glBindImageTexture(1, m_texImageProcessed->textureId(), 0, 0, 0,  GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA8);
    m_shaderComputeH->bind();
    m_shaderComputeH->setUniformValue("radius", radius);
    f->glDispatchCompute(workGroups.width(), workGroups.height(), 1);
    f->glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);
    m_shaderComputeH->release();
    // Compute cleanup
    f->glBindImageTexture(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA8);
    f->glBindImageTexture(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA8);
}
```

and here's the compute shader

```
   /// csErosionFilter.fsh
    #version 430 core
    #define COMPUTEPATCHSIZE 32
    layout (local_size_x = COMPUTEPATCHSIZE, local_size_y = COMPUTEPATCHSIZE) in;
    layout(binding=0, rgba8) uniform readonly highp image2D inputImage;
    layout(binding=1, rgba8) uniform writeonly highp image2D resultImage;
    uniform int radius;
    void main()
    {
        ivec2 imgSize = imageSize(resultImage);
        int x = int(gl_GlobalInvocationID.x);
        int y = int(gl_GlobalInvocationID.y);
        if ((x >= imgSize.x) || (y >= imgSize.y))
            return;

        vec4 newValue = vec4(1);
        int left   = clamp(x - radius, 0, imgSize.x - 1);
        int right  = clamp(x + radius, 0, imgSize.x - 1);
        int top    = clamp(y - radius, 0, imgSize.y - 1);
        int bottom = clamp(y + radius, 0, imgSize.y - 1);
        for (int iX = left; iX <= right; iX++)
        {
            for (int iY = top; iY <= bottom; iY++)
            {
                vec4 value = imageLoad(inputImage, ivec2(iX, iY));
                if(value.x < newValue.x)
                    newValue.x = value.x;
                if(value.y < newValue.y)
                    newValue.y = value.y;
                if(value.z < newValue.z)
                    newValue.z = value.z;
            }
        }

        imageStore(resultImage, ivec2(x,y), newValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick improvement I would suggest using multiple threads to calculate several lines in parallel. You could also use OpenCL or Cuda to achieve this on the GPU, but that would require substantial boilerplate.

I have modified your code to use multiple threads, but I have not tested this, because I currently do not have Qt installed on this device. But this could at least give you a hint on where to start.

(BTW `uchar red, green, blue = 0;` only initializes `blue` with 0, while `red` and `green` stay uninitialized)

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
void applyErosionFilter(QImage &input, int matrixSize)
{
    int filterOffset = (matrixSize - 1) / 2;
    int byteOffset = 0;

    uchar morphResetValue = 255;

    uchar *data = input.bits();
    int stride = input.bytesPerLine();
    uchar *newdata = new uchar[stride * input.height()];

    unsigned num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    if (num_threads == 0)
        num_threads = 1;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    int i = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
    {
        int start = (input.height() - 2 * filterOffset) * i / num_threads;
        int end = (input.height() - 2 * filterOffset) * (i+1) / num_threads;
        threads.emplace_back([&](int start_line, int end_line){
            unsigned char red = 0;
            unsigned char green = 0;
            unsigned char blue = 0;
            for (int y = start_line; y < end_line; y++)
            {
                for (int x = filterOffset; x < input.width() - filterOffset; x++)
                {
                    byteOffset = y * stride + x * 4;

                    red = morphResetValue;
                    green = morphResetValue;
                    blue = morphResetValue;

                    for (int filterY = -filterOffset; filterY <= filterOffset; filterY++)
                    {
                        for (int filterX = -filterOffset; filterX <= filterOffset; filterX++)
                        {
                            i = byteOffset + (filterX * 4) + (filterY * stride);

                            if (data[i] < red)
                                red = data[i];

                            if (data[i + 1] < green)
                                green = data[i + 1];

                            if (data[i + 2] < blue)
                                blue = data[i + 2];
                        }
                    }

                    newdata[byteOffset] = red;
                    newdata[byteOffset + 1] = green;
                    newdata[byteOffset + 2] = blue;
                    newdata[byteOffset + 3] = 255;
                }
            }
        },
            start, end);
    }
    for (auto &thread : threads)
        thread.join();

    input = input.fromImage(QImage(newdata, input.width(), input.height(), QImage::Format::Format_ARGB32));
    delete [] newdata;
}
```

Comment: I'd agree with you that if this code was multi-threaded it would've executed much faster than this, but the problem is that this function gets called from within a loop which already makes use of multi-threading. this is why i wanted to make use of the unused computational power of the GPU

Comment: @MostafaMahmoud Ok, in that case OpenGL/CL would be the most portable way to go, I think. Since you are using Qt, you should be able to create an OpenGL context for a `QOffscreenSurface`, create a Texture from your `QImage` and write a shader that implements the erosion filter. Then render a quad using the texture and the shader and store the result in a `QOpenGLFramebufferObject` which converts back to a `QImage`. You wouldn't even need compute shaders for that.

Comment: i don't know how to write a shader that implements a filter in OpenGL plus, wouldn't this be a very long way to do such a simple task?
anyway, i would like to try this way, so if anyone can provide some code sample this would accelerate my progress

Comment: In general for such filters, you would render a quad with your image as the texture. In the fragment shader, you would then sample the texture like you currently do in your two inner loops and set the fragment color to the result. There are many examples for these fragment shaders online. https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Bloom for example contains a fragment shader that applies gaussian blur under the "Gaussian Blur" section. The rest of that article is not relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use multi-threading: cut the image horizontally in bands and process them separately. I did it with OpenMP, it's really strait forward.
2. A squared structuring element of size NxN can be decomposed in two segments (horizontal and vertical) of size 1xN and Nx1. So instead of doing NxN tests per pixel, you will do 2xN: N=3 9 vs 6, n=5 25 vs 10, etc. Much faster!
3. Use the algorithm(s) already implemented in the following libraries: [SMIL](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bb15/0f6faf198af78f65e710a4ac44d844bd830e.pdf?_ga=2.125139978.1478058719.1568659899-428947554.1568659899) by Matthieu Faessel (C++ auto-vectorized code based on lines comparison, fastest!!!), [libmorpho](https://orbi.uliege.be/handle/2268/121494) by Marc Van Droogenbroeck (C++ but limited to 8 bits encoding if I am right), or [Fulguro](http://fulguro.sourceforge.net/group__group__fulguro__morpho.html) by Christophe Clienti (Lambert algorithm that is a good fit for SIMD optimizations). As you can see in these libraries, they use smart approaches/algorithms/architectures to get fast results. What you developed is the basic that is taught in courses for an easy understanding, but it's the slowest!